# How to organize the data stored in S3 buckets by users on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've allocated AWS buckets for my own projects and my own use, but I've never set them up for other users to use via a website. This will be an abstract question, as I don't know how to move forward:

I am building a platform whereby registered users at one point can upload data. The amount of data is appropriately 100 MB for transaction, which isn't small.

How do I organize the data stored by user, by bucket? I suspect I can keep track of all transactions by tagging username, or tagging by other metadata. Is there a more scalable approach? This feels like it would take a great deal of manual work.

Comment: You can create multiple questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use metadata or tags on your bucket objects. For instance you could tag with a username.

To prevent load on your system, you could put an API Gateway in front of your S3 bucket and allow API Gateway's throttling functionality to prevent certain load. Check out [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html).